# Count the occurrence of a specific character in a string by using substring in Scala

Tags: scala

I am very new to programming. And I'm being asked to count the occurrence of  a specific character in a string by using substring and recursion in scala. I am totally lost and I don't know how to check the equality of the second character in that string. I am not supposed to use tailrecursion and map. Many thanks!

My code so far looks like this:

```
def countChars(str:String, chr:Char):Int = {
    if (str.length == 0)  0
    else {
    if (chr == str.substring(0,1)) 1
    else 0}   + countChars()
}
println(countChars())
```

Comment: You're meant to use *recursion*, but not *tail recursion*??

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is a working version (Haven't used the shortest version to make it easier to read):

```
def countChars(str: String, chr: Char): Int = {
   if (str.length == 0) {
     0
   } else {
     (if (chr.toString() == str.substring(0, 1)) {
        1
     } else {
        0
     }) + countChars(str.substring(1), chr)
   }
}

println(countChars("Hello World", 'l'))         //> 3
```

You had two problems. First you didn't call countChars with the right parameters. And more important and maybe not very obvious: You compared a Char with a String. This will never be true:

```
chr == str.substring(0,1)
```

Because `==` or `equals` are both checking the type first, this is different. Just use a typecast or in this case a simple `toString` like I did.

Hope this helps you.

**Edit** Sorry just pressed the post button accidentily.

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for! Awesome answer! Thanks!

Comment: @sytuacnh, if this is the answer you were looking for, it should be marked as such.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using a match on the existence/value of the first character at each iteration:

```
def countChars(str: String, chr: Char): Int = str.headOption match {
    case None => 0
    case Some(ch) if ch == chr => 1 + countChars(str.substring(1), chr)
    case _ => countChars(str.substring(1), chr) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic scala solution would be:

```
def countChars(str: String, chr: Char): Int = str.filter(_ == chr).length
```

I don't know why you would use `map`, but your question didn't say not to use `filter`

Comment: Actually, idiomatic scala would probably be more like `str.count(_ == chr)` as in `"asdkfjvksjkdkjrw".count(_ == 'j')`

Comment: OP mentioned he is supposed to use recursion

Answer (score 1):

A variation from @cokeSchlumpf and @Shadowlands answers,

```
def countChars(s: String, c: Char): Int = {
  if (s.isEmpty) 0
  else if (s.substring(0,1).head == c) 1 + countChars(s.substring(1),c)
  else countChars(s.substring(1),c)
}
```